# MySQL Query Syntax Error on INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone have any ideas why im getting this Syntax error in my query?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO customers
>                 (
>                     name,
>                     email,
>                     address_1,
>                     address_' at line 22

```
INSERT INTO invoices
            (
                invoice, 
                invoice_date, 
                due_date, 
                subtotal, 
                shipping, 
                discount, 
                vat, 
                total
            ) 
            VALUES (
                'AMBMN0001',
                '14/05/2015',
                '20/05/2015',
                '985.45',
                '23',
                '90.55',
                '197.09',
                '1008.45'
            );
        INSERT INTO customers
            (
                name,
                email,
                address_1,
                address_2,
                town,
                county,
                postcode,
                phone,
                name_ship,
                address_1_ship,
                address_2_ship,
                town_ship,
                county_ship,
                postcode_ship
            ) 
            VALUES (
                'James Brandon',
                'james@ambientlounge.com',
                '5 Some Road',
                'Town',
                'County',
                'Other',
                'POSTCODE',
                '0748646013845',
                'James Brandon',
                '5 Some Road',
                'Town',
                'County',
                'Other',
                'POSTCODE'
            );
        INSERT INTO invoice_items
        (
            invoice,
            product,
            qty,
            price,
            discount,
            subtotal
        )
        VALUES (
            'AMBMN0001',
            'Versa Table - Wildberry',
            '3',
            '200',
            '10%',
            '540.00'
        );
    INSERT INTO invoice_items
        (
            invoice,
            product,
            qty,
            price,
            discount,
            subtotal
        )
        VALUES (
            'AMBMN0001',
            'Versa Table - Aubergine',
            '1',
            '178',
            '30.55',
            '147.45'
        );
    INSERT INTO invoice_items
        (
            invoice,
            product,
            qty,
            price,
            discount,
            subtotal
        )
        VALUES (
            'AMBMN0001',
            'Versa Table - Blue Jazz',
            '2',
            '149',
            '',
            '298.00'
        );
```

PHP

```
 // Create invoice
if ($action == 'create_invoice'){

    // invoice customer information
    // billing
    $customer_name = $_POST['customer_name']; // customer name
    $customer_email = $_POST['customer_email']; // customer email
    $customer_address_1 = $_POST['customer_address_1']; // customer address
    $customer_address_2 = $_POST['customer_address_2']; // customer address
    $customer_town = $_POST['customer_town']; // customer town
    $customer_county = $_POST['customer_county']; // customer county
    $customer_postcode = $_POST['customer_postcode']; // customer postcode
    $customer_phone = $_POST['customer_phone']; // customer phone number

    //shipping
    $customer_name_ship = $_POST['customer_name_ship']; // customer name (shipping)
    $customer_address_1_ship = $_POST['customer_address_1_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
    $customer_address_2_ship = $_POST['customer_address_2_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
    $customer_town_ship = $_POST['customer_town_ship']; // customer town (shipping)
    $customer_county_ship = $_POST['customer_county_ship']; // customer county (shipping)
    $customer_postcode_ship = $_POST['customer_postcode_ship']; // customer postcode (shipping)

    // invoice details
    $invoice = $_POST['invoice_id']; // invoice number
    $invoice_date = $_POST['invoice_date']; // invoice date
    $invoice_due_date = $_POST['invoice_due_date']; // invoice due date
    $invoice_subtotal = $_POST['invoice_subtotal']; // invoice sub-total
    $invoice_shipping = $_POST['invoice_shipping']; // invoice shipping amount
    $invoice_discount = $_POST['invoice_discount']; // invoice discount
    $invoice_vat = $_POST['invoice_vat']; // invoice vat
    $invoice_total = $_POST['invoice_total']; // invoice total

    // insert invoice into database
    $query = "INSERT INTO invoices (
                    invoice, 
                    invoice_date, 
                    invoice_due_date, 
                    subtotal, 
                    shipping, 
                    discount, 
                    vat, 
                    total
                ) VALUES (
                    '".$invoice."',
                    '".$invoice_date."',
                    '".$invoice_due_date."',
                    '".$invoice_subtotal."',
                    '".$invoice_shipping."',
                    '".$invoice_discount."',
                    '".$invoice_vat."',
                    '".$invoice_total."'
                );
            ";
        // insert customer details into database
    $query .= "INSERT INTO customers (
                    invoice,
                    name,
                    email,
                    address_1,
                    address_2,
                    town,
                    county,
                    postcode,
                    phone,
                    name_ship,
                    address_1_ship,
                    address_2_ship,
                    town_ship,
                    county_ship,
                    postcode_ship
                ) VALUES (
                    '".$invoice."',
                    '".$customer_name."',
                    '".$customer_email."',
                    '".$customer_address_1."',
                    '".$customer_address_2."',
                    '".$customer_town."',
                    '".$customer_county."',
                    '".$customer_postcode."',
                    '".$customer_phone."',
                    '".$customer_name_ship."',
                    '".$customer_address_1_ship."',
                    '".$customer_address_2_ship."',
                    '".$customer_town_ship."',
                    '".$customer_county_ship."',
                    '".$customer_postcode_ship."'
                );
            ";

    // invoice product items
    foreach($_POST['invoice_product'] as $key => $value) {
        $item_product = $value;
        // $item_description = $_POST['invoice_product_desc'][$key];
        $item_qty = $_POST['invoice_product_qty'][$key];
        $item_price = $_POST['invoice_product_price'][$key];
        $item_discount = $_POST['invoice_product_discount'][$key];
        $item_subtotal = $_POST['invoice_product_sub'][$key];

        // insert invoice items into database
        $query .= "INSERT INTO invoice_items (
                invoice,
                product,
                qty,
                price,
                discount,
                subtotal
            ) VALUES (
                '".$invoice."',
                '".$item_product."',
                '".$item_qty."',
                '".$item_price."',
                '".$item_discount."',
                '".$item_subtotal."'
            );
        ";

    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    // execute the query
    if($mysqli -> query($query)){
        //if saving success
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'Success',
            'message' => 'Invoice has been created successfully!'
        ));
    } else {
        // if unable to create invoice
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'Error',
            //'message' => 'There has been an error, please try again.'
            // debug
            'message' => 'There has been an error, please try again.<pre>'.$mysqli->error.'</pre><pre>'.$query.'</pre>'
        ));
    }

    //close database connection
    $mysqli->close();

}
```

Comment: You have missed terminator (`;`) after each insert statement

Comment: Still getting the issue with those in

Comment: Please update your query where you inserted your semicolon's

Comment: 3rd, 4th and 5th inserts _qty_ appears twice

Comment: Updated, and moved double qty thanks guys - still getting issue with what i updated

Comment: Remove space between phone and name_ship in customer table query.

Comment: Removed space still same issue :(

Comment: Are you getting this error in a script, or by direct input into mysql?

Comment: Im using PHP to insert and done a $mysqli->error which showed that error and also printed $query so it outputs all the queries. I did run in mySQL as well and get same result.

Comment: Weird, if i paste that query directly into mysql if works fine...

Comment: Do you get the same result when you run the queries separately?

Comment: It seems to work when i do directly into phpmyadmin with the generated $query - im confused why its not working from my script and errors. I also pasted the generated query into a SQL syntax checker and get some error result.... strange.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , should change date format as 
'2015/05/14',
'2015/05/20',

Comment: Date is just being stored as text, should not matter really plus I want the date format as it is (UK Standard) but cannot see that being the issue.

Comment: INSERT INTO invoices ( invoice, invoice_date, due_date, subtotal, shipping, discount, vat, total ) VALUES ( 'AMBMN0001', '2015/05/14', '201505/20/', '985.45', '23', '90.55', '197.09', '1008.45' )  i tested it working fine..check this..

Comment: Table structure id int(20)
 invoice varchar(200)    
   invoice_date date 
 due_date date     
 subtotal int(100)
 shipping float(6,2)
    discount float(6,2) 
 vat float(6,2)  
     total int(100)

Comment: see date i have set at varchar(255) - plus the error im getting is not on the invoice part its the customer part...

Comment: I changed to date on both of those, still same issue, i think because its not that part thats the issue but stops at shipping part as per my desc above.

Comment: INSERT INTO customers ( name, email, address_1, address_2, town, county, postcode, phone, name_ship, address_1_ship, address_2_ship, town_ship, county_ship, postcode_ship ) VALUES ( 'James Brandon', 'james@ambientlounge.com', '5 Some Road', 'Town', 'County', 'Other', 'POSTCODE', '0748646013845', 'James Brandon', '5 Some Road', 'Town', 'County', 'Other', 'POSTCODE' )   check once table structure.

Comment: So i pasted all of the queries in phpmyadmin and loaded in fine, any ideas why its not from the PHP script and giving me that error? its weird.

Comment: Found issue! needed to be multi_query not query!

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problem in stead of:

```
if($mysqli -> query($query)){
```

Needed to use

```
if($mysqli -> multi_query($query)){
```